# Dynamically created checkbox click detect with no class or id Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have some checkboxes like the following which are dynamically created.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="feature[]" value="9">
```

As you can see there is **no id or class** with it. And **name** property is of the type array. Now I can't detect the check event on these checkboxes. I need to detect the events and at the same time their values in which events have occurred.

I've checked several examples regarding this, but usually they all used **class** or **id** or **name**.But name is not in array type in those examples. I've tried with the name property to use, but couldn't manage. Please help.......

Comment: hi check this out exactly wat ur looking out for http://jsfiddle.net/M2Jnx/122/

Comment: Thank you @codebreaker It is exactly same that I wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
$("input[name^='feature']").click(function(){
   alert($(this).val());
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name="feature[]"]', function(){
    //do something
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <input type="text" name="feature" value="123" />

    $("input").click(function(){
     var txt = $(this).val();
     alert(txt);
     alert($(this).attr("name"));
    });

Try this once
```